# Where linux signals are sent or processed inside the kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, signals, abort

How is the signalling(interrupts) mechanism handled in kernel? The cause why I ask is: somehow a SIGABRT signal is received by my application and I want to find where does that come from..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be looking in your application for the cause, not in the kernel.

Usually a process receives `SIGABRT` when it directly calls `abort` or when an `assert` fails. Finding exactly the piece of the kernel that delivers the signal will gain you nothing.

In conclusion, your code or a library your code is using is causing this. See [`abort(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/abort.3.html) and [`assert`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/assert.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

cnicutar's answer is the best guess IMHO.

It is possible that the signal has been emitted by another process, although in the case of SIGBART it most likely to be emitted by the same process which receives it via the `abort(3)` libc function.

In doubt, you can run your application with `strace -e kill yourapp you args ...` to quickly check if that `kill` system call is indeed invoked from within your program or dependent libraries. Or use gdb `catch syscall`.

Note that in some cases the kernel itself can emit signals, such as a `SIGKILL` when the infamous "OOM killer" goes into action.

BTW, signals are delivered asynchronously, they disrupt the normal workflow of your program. This is why they're painful to trace. Besides machinery such as SystemTap I don't know how to trace or log signals emission and delivery within the kernel.

Comment: `abort` delivers its signal synchronously.  All you need is a core dump or to run under a debugger to find exactly where it is being called.